# In the indent-rainbow extension, I want to exclude JS and JSX files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsx

In the indent-rainbow extension, I want to exclude JS and JSX files. But after trying all the given instructions in `settings.json`, it is not working for me. What langauge name should I give in `settings.json`?

`settings.json`

```json
"indentRainbow.excludedLanguages": ["javascript", "js", "*.jsx", "plaintext"]
```

Indent-rainbow extension:

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please fix your formatting. It is considerably harder to answer your question if you are using images instead of code blocks. Please replace your images with code blocks, so it is better for accessibility and easier to read / reproduce. **Please do not post images of code!** Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language name in vscode for .jsx files is actually javascriptreact. This is why excludedLanguages doesn't work for you. You can look it up in the language chooser (part inside parenthesis). [image]

Comment: By running the Change Language Mode command (Ctrl+K M) to show this menu.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file